# How to create a JavaScript function to lookup objects and arrays nested within each other

Tags: javascript, object, recursion, nested

I have an object with nested arrays and object that looks like this:

```js
// Recursive nested objects & arrays:
var obj = {
  children: [{
      parentname: "level 0, Benny",
      children: [{
          parentname: "level 0.0, Stevey",
          children: [{
              parentname: "level 0.0.0, Betty",
              children: []
            },
            {
              parentname: "level 0.0.1, AFGNCAAP",
              children: [{
                parentname: "level 0.0.1.0, Moonman",
                children: []
              }]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          parentname: "level 0.1, Oreo",
          children: []
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      parentname: "level 1, Jupiter",
      children: []
    }
  ]
};

// I am able to retrieve values with various length formulas:
console.log(obj.children[0].parentname); // level 0, Benny
console.log(obj.children[0].children[0].parentname); // level 0.0, Stevey
console.log(obj.children[0].children[0].children[0].parentname); // level 0.0.0, Betty
console.log(obj.children[0].children[0].children[1].parentname); // level 0.0.1, AFGNCAAP
console.log(obj.children[0].children[0].children[1].children[0].parentname); // level 0.0.1.0, Moonman
console.log(obj.children[0].children[1].parentname); // level 0.1, Oreo
console.log(obj.children[1].parentname); // level 1, Jupiter


// And I able to reduce formulas into functions...per level of nesting, example 1 level:
function getNameWorking1(name, level) {
  console.log(obj[name][level].parentname);
}
getNameWorking1(["children"], [1]) // level 1, Jupiter

// And example 2 levels:
function getNameWorking2(name, level) {
  console.log(obj[name][level[0]][name][level[1]].parentname);
}
getNameWorking2(["children"], [
  [0],
  [1]
]) // level 0.1, Oreo

// I am trying to create a single function that I can send a parameter with the sequence of property name & array values.  This does not work:
function getNameNotWorking(parameter) {
  console.log(obj[parameter].parentname);
}
getNameNotWorking("[children][1]");
getNameNotWorking("[children][0][children][1]");
```

I am trying to create a single function that I can send a parameter with the sequence of property name & array values. This last function is not working.  Any help on how to do this?

BTW. I have a recursive function that does work for this.  But it works by every time starting at the beginning and look reading through each nested object & array until the item I am looking for is found.  This seems it may be excessive to do repetitively.  So I am looking for a method to look up the object once I already know it location - via all the children array values.

Comment: _"This seems it may be excessive to do repetitively..."_ - don't prematurely optimize

Comment: Can you post the working code that you have, please? I don't understand what you mean by "*once I already know it location*".

Comment: @adam my upvote ?

Comment: @Gaurav Saraswat, I tried to upvote earlier and it told me I couldn't...I think something because my rank was too low.  Sorry I am new, I just created an account.  But it let me upvote now!.  I do thank you very much!

Comment: ohh. no worries . all the best :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel you should `pass your parameters separated by white sapace` instead of swrapping in square brackets to make **parsing and solution easier**.

And. here you go :)

```js
function getNameWorking1(parameter, obj) {
  paramsList = parameter.split(' ').filter(prop => Boolean(prop)).map(prop => prop.trim());

  return paramsList.reduce((val, prop) => {
    return val[prop];
  }, obj).parentname;
}


//Working example:

var obj = {
  children: [{
      parentname: "level 0, Benny",
      children: [{
          parentname: "level 0.0, Stevey",
          children: [{
              parentname: "level 0.0.0, Betty",
              children: []
            },
            {
              parentname: "level 0.0.1, AFGNCAAP",
              children: [{
                parentname: "level 0.0.1.0, Moonman",
                children: []
              }]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          parentname: "level 0.1, Oreo",
          children: []
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      parentname: "level 1, Jupiter",
      children: []
    }
  ]
};

console.log(getNameWorking1("children 1", obj));
console.log(getNameWorking1("children 0 children 1", obj));
```

Comment: I modified this to reduce this slightly, make reusable for other keys, and created similar set function.  I’m new to this so I don’t know the best way to share my modifications, so I posted them at [link](https://codepen.io/sassano/pen/qvBXbN?editors=1111). Let me known what you think.

Comment: yes. i copy pasted your prev. code in comment and that is equivalently correct

Answer (score 0):

Your function doesn't work because it's taking the full string `"[children][1]"` and adding it in place of `parameter`, i.e. it's looking up `obj["[children][1]"].parentname`, which is undefined.

You need to input each key as parameters individually. Since you can't know how many parameters need to be passed, you need to iterate through the global [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) object.

Therefore, your function would look something like this:

```
function getNameNotWorking() {
  var returnValue = obj;
  for (let i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    returnValue = returnValue[arguments[i]];
  }
    console.log(returnValue);
}
```

Click [here](https://codepen.io/mikeshort10/pen/VRwmmE) for working Codepen example.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this using regex and `reduce`

```js
const obj = {children:[{parentname:"level 0, Benny",children:[{parentname:"level 0.0, Stevey",children:[{parentname:"level 0.0.0, Betty",children:[]},{parentname:"level 0.0.1, AFGNCAAP",children:[{parentname:"level 0.0.1.0, Moonman",children:[]}]}]},{parentname:"level 0.1, Oreo",children:[]}]},{parentname:"level 1, Jupiter",children:[]}]}

const getNested = (object, str) => {
  let matches = [],
      match,
      regex = /\[(.*?)\]/g;

  while (match = regex.exec(str)) {
    matches.push(match[1]);
  }

  return matches.reduce((acc, key) => (acc || {})[key], object)
}

const nested = getNested(obj, "[children][0][children][1]")

console.log(nested)
```

- Use `/\[(.*?)\]/g` to get the key names in a capturing group ([Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/dWbXdj/1))
- Use **[`exec`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec)** to get all the key names from the capturing group to an array

  ```
  // matches
  ["children", "0", "children", "1" ]
  ```
- Use **[`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)** to recursively get the nested property from the object

Answer (score -1):

Check out [JsonPath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath). It provides a clean interface around selecting JSON attributes without objects and there are plenty of JavaScript SDKs for it.

Comment: Which JavaScript implementation would you think of? And most importantly, how would you apply it to the OP's specific problem?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonpath looks to be the most used JsonPath SDK (for nodejs at least). Combining JsonPath with template strings would likely help alleviate OP's problem, as `obj[parameter].parentname` could be represented as a static JsonPath directive.